# Dokka not generate documentaion

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka

In need to generate an internal documentation with Dokka,
But i've that error ... I don't know why

[build gradle : app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtScf.png)

[build gradle project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmwSP.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX58b.png)

Thanks dudes :)

Answer (score 0):

Please post the full stacktrace for this exception.
Moreover I'd suggest using the newest dokka version, which is `0.10.1`. On the newest version the Android plugin has been merged with the Gradle plugin, so instead of applying `org.jetbrains.dokka-android` you can just apply `org.jetbrains.dokka`.

Please post code as code blocks and not as images, it will be hard to find this problem later